# Supress default browser: Java, Android studio

Tags: java, android, browser, webview

I'm setting up a simple AI, chat functions etc. Right now, I'm working on a small web view "browser". Opens up to google by default, then has a little textedit and button for further navigation. However, whenever a link is clicked on or I try to navigate, it opens the default browser instead. I tried using some code from simmilar questions, but it led to further issues so I removed it. Thanks for any help, here's my code:

Xml, manifest, and method for button:

```
manifest file
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai.Browser"
        android:parentActivityName="comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai.Main" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai.Main" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

```
<Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Browser"
            android:id="@+id/startBrowser"
            android:onClick="StartBrowser"
            android:layout_above="@+id/btnSay"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/lblOutput"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/lblOutput" />

public void StartBrowser(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Browser.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Code for Browser.java(Second activity)

```
package comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class Browser extends Activity {
    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webBrowser);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        String url = "http://google.com";
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Errors:

```
   11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai, PID: 24169
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:278)
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4497)
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18590)
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:273)
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4497) 
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18590) 
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021) 
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827) 
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643) 
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai/android.provider.Browser}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1723)
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1511)
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:784)
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at comi.coding.prometheus.ignisai.Main.StartBrowser(Main.java:251)
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:273) 
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4497) 
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18590) 
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021) 
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827) 
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643) 
11-11 20:38:34.831 24169-24169/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was something to do with the way the intent or manifest was being used. I found an in depth tutorial I replicated, and now it's calling on the second activity. The code you provided isn't quite working (The web view itself isn't loading, yet a button and text edit in the same layout are) and while some layout is being called,  Log.d("Tag Name", "Browser class running"); shows it isn't being called. Anyway, I totally redid the manifest and how it called on the second activity and it's working. I believe the exact change that fixed it was adding this to the manifest:

```
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this inside your button click :

```
  mWebView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.yourID);
  mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
```

Add this as a class inside your class:

```
private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
      @Override
      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
         view.loadUrl(url);
         return true;
      }
   }
```

This is a simple example class for using WebView:

```
 public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {
        private WebView webView;    

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);

            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

            String url = "http://google.com";
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.loadUrl(url);       
        }

        private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        }   
    }
```

This is all you need for doing this. Compare your code with this

Comment: I added it into my startBrowser method and it generated a 143320 word error

Comment: The log is too long to post, but I'll see how many I can put.

Comment: Played around trying to move it to a better location, have the right imports etc. Errors are a lot smaller now, there's just two that keep repeating them. I'll update the post.

Comment: It should also be noted this errors prevent it from running in the first place

Comment: First of all, remove unwanted codes and multiple codes.Use everything in right place and remove multiple instantiations

Comment: I removed the code for the web browser in the on create method, but everything else I want or studio automatically generated. Should I delete the auto generated code?

Comment: What is your output now?

Comment: At first it appeared the same, but I found 3 additional errors that also repeat. I'll post them as well

Comment: I'll try it in a minute when I get back to my desktop, thanks.

Comment: Tried it every way I could, even setting up a seperate activity for it. Still wont even run and gives the same errors

Comment: With the seperate activity it only crashes when I run your code. I set it up so on a button push it starts the other activity. The other activity is all your code, just changing the ids.

Comment: What crash did you get?

Comment: Updated, I'll also post the code for the button and my second activity.

Comment: Check your crash log. `have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml` . Didn't u see this?

Comment: Yes, did you see the manifest I posted? I could have declared it wrong, but I did have code for it. Fairly new to this. I appreciate all the help btw

Comment: You have to declare all activities in your Manifest file if you want to use it. Do that first

Comment: Add like this : `<activity
            android:name=".Browser">
        </activity>`

Comment: Changed the activity declaration to match yours, had no effect